# close the cmd.exe if statement has a conditions are false/true

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

I have a question in python script that I've build in while

how can I close the **full window** of **(cmd.exe)** depending on  **IF/ELSE** statement

like

```
#python script:    
  if x = 1 : 
    #script_continue..
  else: 
    print('ops')
    exit() #close the total cmd.exe window automatically not just the python script
```

I try different methods but not work as I want

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First: if x = 1 is an assignment, not a comparison.

if x == 1 # this is the right way

Second, check this out: [Python to close own CMD shell window on exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46873212/python-to-close-own-cmd-shell-window-on-exit)